# How to download files from node express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, express

I have a file on my server (Node.js +  Express). I need to download file from server to computer of user. 
in React app I call the function which would download file:

```
downloadFileFromServer(file) { // file -- name of file
fetch(`${Config.baseUrl}/download-file/${this.props.params.idEvent}/${file}`, {
  method: 'GET'
})
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error('Bad response from server');
      }
      return response;
    });
```

}

On backend I have this route:

```
app.route('/download-file/:idEvent/:fileName')
.get((req, res) => {
  const id = `id${req.params.idEvent}`;
  const dir = `${Config.basePath}/${id}/${req.params.fileName}`;

  res.download(dir); // dir -- path to server's files. (something like this: 'var/www/... path to directory ...')
});
```

In result I haven't any results. Nothing happend, consoles (frontend, backend) are empty, without errors.

Why I can't download file? How to fix it?

Comment: `fetch` doesn't return data directly. You likely need to call `response.blob` or `response.text` first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Why are you concatenating id with req.params.idEvent?  Is your param id always starting with “id” i.e. id43768926?

Comment: try this location.path = `${Config.baseUrl}/download-file/${this.props.params.idEvent}/${file}` in your download logic

Answer (score 3):

you have to install "js-file-download" library in react using following command

```
npm install --save js-file-download
```

then  the code in react file as follows:

```
 import download from 'js-file-download';
downloadFile = () => {
   axios.get("localhost:3030/getfile")
     .then(resp => {
            download(resp.data, fileName);
     });
}
```

the code at server side is as follows:

```
router.get("/getfile", (req, res) => {
  FileLocation ="public/FILE.pdf"
  file="File.pdf"
 res.download(fileLocation, file, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
});
```

My reference for this answer is in this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/bbtmi8/download_file_from_node_express_server_to_react/).

This works for me.I hope it works for you.

Comment: the link is missing

Comment: missing link added.Thank you I forgot to add