# Download file from Express API using React and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

**When using a React client with an Express API, how can the React client download a file that was send by the Express API?**

Problem:

- If I type the url into my browser bar and press enter the file downloads successfully.
- But if I call the same url in my React app using Axios, the file does not download.

**Express server**

```js
// Route handler for /api/files/testfile
const getFile = async (req, res, next) => {

    // File
    const fileName = 'file.csv';
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../../public/', fileName);

    // File options
     const options = {
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true,
            'content-disposition': "attachment; filename=" + fileName, // gets ignored
            'content-type': "text/csv"
        }
    }

    try {
        res.download(
            filePath,
            fileName,
            options
        );
        console.log("File sent successfully!");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error("File could not be sent!");
        next(error);
    }
});
```

**React client**

```js
// When the user clicks the "Download as CSV" button
handleDownloadFile = () => {
    axios
        .get(
            `/api/files/testfile`, {
                responseType: 'blob',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
                }
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.headers); // does not include content-disposition
            console.log("File downloading successfully!");
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.error("File could not be downloaded:", error);
        });
}
```

I read that this might have to do with the `content-disposition` header. I tried setting in (see my above code) but the header does not get send to the client.

---

**Undesirable "solutions":**

- In the React app: Create a new `a` element, set its `href` attribute and trigger a `click` via JavaScript. I am looking for a solution that does not require this JS hack.
- In the React app: Use `a` with `target="_blank"` instead of Axios. However, that is not suitable for me, as it would bypass my axios config settings (API url, auth token, etc)

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you have to tell axios where the file is directly based on this example:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/example.pdf',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

I would assume you can simply change the response on your api to return the blob using a new Blob for the file. But the main part of what it seems to require is the .then response on your axios get call. This way you can still authenticate users' status with jwt and protect your files appropriately.

Comment: After one day of struggle. FINALLY!!!. I shall wish you a happy Christmas and a long blessed life for helping me. You are the man!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no reliable, cross-platform methods for triggering the browser's download behavior for normal web pages is available that will fit the bill here. Since you can't use a plain URL w/ content-disposition, redirects, or a Data URI on a normal DOM anchor tag, I don't see another way to cause the download without creating a hidden `a` and clicking it. However, this seems to work well (and is indeed the mechanism used by popular utilities like [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/))

Building a crude `DownloadButton` component to do this in React is pretty simple. [Here's a working codepen](https://codepen.io/HackedByChinese/pen/LYYzvJE) that mocks the Axios response and otherwise works beginning to end, barring any refactoring you would like to do. I am using hooks and `async/await` for my own sanity/clarity, but neither is strictly necessary. It does use the [`download` attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) on anchor tags, which has good support across modern browsers.

```
function getFileNameFromContentDisposition(contentDisposition) {
  if (!contentDisposition) return null;

  const match = contentDisposition.match(/filename="?([^"]+)"?/);

  return match ? match[1] : null;
}

const DownloadButton = ({ children, fileName, loadingText }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    let res = null;

    try {
      // add any additional headers, such as authorization, as the second parameter to get below
      // also, remember to use responseType: 'blob' if working with blobs instead, and use res.blob() instead of res.data below
      res = await axios.get(`/api/files/${fileName}`);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(err);
      return;
    }

    const data = res.data; // or res.blob() if using blob responses

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([data], {
        type: res.headers["content-type"]
      })
    );

    const actualFileName = getFileNameFromContentDisposition(
      res.headers["content-disposition"]
    );

    // uses the download attribute on a temporary anchor to trigger the browser
    // download behavior. if you need wider compatibility, you can replace this
    // part with a library such as filesaver.js
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", actualFileName);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
  };

  if (error) {
    return (<div>Unable to download file: {error.message}</div>);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} disabled={loading}>
      {loading ? loadingText || "Please wait..." : children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

As for `content-disposition` not showing in the response headers from ExpressJS, I am not sure what the issue is. However, according to the [ExpressJS docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download), the second parameter is the filename which will be automatically sent as a `content-disposition` header so you should not need to specify it yourself in the `options` parameter. Do the other parameters show up? If so, maybe there's a conflict in redefining it `options`. However, I'm experiencing no troubles either way when running an example locally with a route similar to yours.

> res.download(path [, filename] [, options] [, fn])
>
> The optional options argument is supported by Express v4.16.0 onwards.
>
> Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers
>   will prompt the user for download. By default, the Content-Disposition
>   header “filename=” parameter is path (this typically appears in the
>   browser dialog). Override this default with the filename parameter.
>
> When an error occurs or transfer is complete, the method calls the
>   optional callback function fn. This method uses res.sendFile() to
>   transfer the file.
>
> The optional options argument passes through to the underlying
>   res.sendFile() call, and takes the exact same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install "js-file-download" library in react using following command

```
npm install --save js-file-download
```

code in react file using axios as follows:

```
 import download from 'js-file-download';
 downloadFile = () => {
   axios.get("localhost:3000/route/path/url")
     .then(resp => {
            download(resp.data, fileName);
     });
}
```

Comment: It corrupts my downloaded file.

Comment: please refer to answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171911/how-to-download-files-from-node-express-server/61746528?noredirect=1#comment109219285_61746528) @PrathameshMore